# Hide blank lines on google dev tools in the sources pane

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, user-interface, developer-tools

I am using chrome's dev tools to debug an application.I was wondering how can i hide the empty lines that appear in a Javascript file.To be more specific,in the sources pane,i can see the javasript that accompanies the html page.There is a huge gap from line 2001 to 3454 and then there is javascript code again.I would like to make the code read better,so i would prefer not to view the empty lines.It this possible?
Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the [Pretty Print option](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/javascript-debugging#pretty-print) at the bottom of Chrome's dev tools:

[image]

> If you have trouble trying to read and debug minified JavaScript in
>   the DevTools, a pretty printing option is available to make life
>   easier.
>    ...by clicking on the curly brace  ("Pretty Print") icon in the
>   bottom left corner, the JavaScript is transformed into a more human
>   readable form. This is also more easy for debugging and setting
>   breakpoints.

Comment: Yes i tried that but that does not hide the empty lines.It does make the code more readable though!

Comment: If that doesn't help with the blank lines you'll need to take the code into another resource like a third part website, code editor, or Chrome extension. In terms of built-in help, that's all that Chrome offers.